# .htaccess SSL redirect with url rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I need your help.
Let's say this is my website: example.com

I would like to redirect http to https.
Furthermore I would like also rewrite the url.
If i access the website with:

`https://example.com/new` everything is working fine.

If I access the website with:
`http://www.example.com/new` it redirects to https but will not rewrite the url. The result is this:

```
`https://example.com/old`


RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule  ^new/(.*)$    old/$1    [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

I have tried to put the rules in another order but this wasn't working at all.

I hope you can help me. Many thanks:)

Comment: switch the order of your rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only trying to remove `www`, you just need this.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule  ^new/(.*)$    old/$1    [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I have use your code, it's working fine now. Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The rule

```
RewriteRule  ^new/(.*)$    old/$1    [L,QSA]
```

is configured as `L` (last), hence it no longer processes other rules once it matches.

You need to switch the order of the rules. Add the HTTPS redirect **before** the mentioned rule.

Comment: thanks for the anwser! I have tried putting RewriteRule  ^new/(.*)$    old/$1    [L,QSA] under the other rule, but it isn't working..