# Redirect apache www, https://www to https non-www URLS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I know it's duplicated many times but I promise I tried many different way but still didn't work for me.

I have a https://example.com and it redirect from http and www but it's not covering all URLs.

I want to redirect

1. `www.example.com` to `https://example.com` covered
2. `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` covered
3. `https://www.example.com/about` to `https://example.com/about`
4. `https://www.example.com/#blah` to `https://example.com/#blah`

This is my last time tried `.htaccess` code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}        =off   [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www.example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$          "https://example.com/$1" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

---

**----------------------Updated------------------**

I have no idea how it's worked. I replaced many different rules but this one is only one working.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do you have any other conflicting rules? That should be ok. You don't use $ on 2nd condition. here's a working example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38933907/330987

Comment: Can someone explain that updated rule? how it's working correct?

Comment: Okey I think I had to provide more information like apache server is redirecting http to https not .htaccess file. If apache didn't do that this rule should be failed.

Answer (score 0):

Change yours rules to these:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried before and tried again. It's wordpress website and all admin URLs and home page are fine, but still all other subpages don't redirect to non-www